# Attaching event handler for onerror to an image does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onerror

I am trying to attach an event handler for the `onerror` event to an `img` element so that it will replace it with some text if there is an error while loading it.

I can get it to work in Chrome and Firefox but it will not work in IE. I am using IE11.

This is my image element:

```
<img class="image-class" src="someURL" />
```

And the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var imageError = function (img) {
            $(img).after('<span>Replacement Text</span>');
            $(img).remove();
        };
        var handler = function (e) {
            imageError(e.currentTarget);
        };
        $('.image-class').each(function () {
            $(this).error(handler);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have tried binding the event in the html itself with:

```
<img class="image-class" onerror="imageError(this)" src="someURL" />
```

I noticed when debugging in Chrome that after executing the `$(this).error(handler)` line, the `img` element still had `onerror` defined as `null`.

Does anyone know why this is not working in IE, and how I could get it to work in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, give the following a try - it works just fine in IE 9. I suspect the problem has either to do with jQuery's expectations or the way you've used inline JS to apply the function to the image (possibly a combination of the 2).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onImgError(evt)
{
    console.log("onImgError fired");
    console.log("Img id: " + this.id);

    var parent = this.parentNode;
    var span = newEl('span');
    span.innerHTML = "broken image replacement text";
    parent.insertBefore(span, this);
    parent.removeChild(this);
}

function onDocLoaded()
{
    var mImg = byId('mImg');
    mImg.addEventListener('error', onImgError, false);
    mImg.src = "imgs/girl.png";
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <img id='mImg' title='image error test'/>
</body>
</html>
```